# Is there any way to accurately increase CR based on an excess of party wealth?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, encounter-design, wealth

If playing milestone leveling a ramping of treasure can occur in which the party gains gold and magical items far beyond what their normal wealth would be at a level.

And yes this issue can be avoided if you carefully amend treasure to lower values over time to even things out. But in my particular case I did not do a good job of this and thus have players who have a great deal more gold than would be normal at their level but would be normal for the amount of creatures they have defeated.

But the question here is, if the party does have more wealth than is normal for their level, say they have the wealth of a 9th level character at 6th or 7th level. Is there any accurate way to determine how much higher CR's of encounters should be in order to present appropriate Very easy, Easy, Challenging, and Very difficult encounters?

Comment: Although it's not really a *per se* duplicate, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/24778/8610)'s answers may end up being what you *actually* need.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Very helpful! But I am still most interested in if there is a formula to simply increase encounter CR (and I will also be giving out less wealth until things even out) Basically looking at this as a part of the solution if that makes any sense...

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but one thing that helps in encounter design is pick enemies that naturally counter some of their more powerful items, if possible. For instance, if their new helm causes an area Frightened condition, *occasionally* fighting fear immune creatures is an acceptable way to make them spend resources. Additionally, leveraging longer 'adventuring days' (encounters per rest) can help increase the apparent difficulty without actually adjusting anything.

Answer (score 2):

#### No, there isn't a table that exactly identifies CR increase based on party wealth.

The DMG explicitly calls this the DM's job in the game (DMG, p54):

> Your job is to compare the wealth gained from the encounters in your adventure with the expected wealth gain shown on the table above.  If your adventure has more treasure, reduce it.

and (p212)

> Including magic items as part of a treasure is a vital task of the DM.  ...A single overpowering item can ruin a whole campaign.

However, both the DMG and the DMG II have a number of resources for modifying encounter difficulty to suit players who are struggling or overpowering equal-EL encounters.  On page 49 of the DMG, the section "Single Monster Encounters" provides some tips to heighten difficulty, such as "Prepare tactics in advance" or "Split up the party." On page 50, there's another section explicitly titled "Modifying Difficulty," discussing further tactics to increase the effective challenge of lower-CR enemies.  The DMG II also contains a wealth of resources for 'spicing up' encounters by means such as making them in exotic environments (eg, aerial or underwater combats), which may force the players to acquire and use consumables they wouldn't have otherwise needed.

Overall, the advice seems to be:

1. Don't worry too much about adjusting short-term XP gain.  If you gently reduce treasure, the players will 'catch up' to their gear.
2. Increase the difficulty for well-equipped characters by making their enemies well-prepared as well.
3. Create novel encounters which encourage the players to consume more resources.

And from my own experience, one possibility is to allow the players to expend or trade in some of that wealth for some in-game reason.  For good parties, this might be a heroic act (rebuilding a destroyed town) or noble purpose (expanding a Good religious organization).  For neutral or evil parties, it might be some investment that will pay off later (magical research that will yield new items or spells -- when it's level-appropriate) or personal status (titles of nobility, complete with lands and serfs).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are misusing a few common terms, so let me clarify them.

**Challenge Rating**

> Each monster in that book has a Challenge Rating (CR) that, when compared to party level, translates directly into an XP award. A Challenge Rating is a measure of how easy or difficult a monster or trap is to overcome. (Dungeon Master's Guide, page 36)

The **Party Level** is the average level of all characters in the party, including player characters and npcs.

ECL
The effective character level (ECL) of a creature determines how powerful it is as a character or a cohort. The  Monster Manual contains statistics and other details on potential cohorts. Take the level adjustment plus the Hit Dice (including class hit dice) to generate ECL.

### A little more about adventurers and economy

Remember that unless something is a trade good, like gems, pieces of art, magic items **it is sold by half of it's market price.** Keep in mind, that player character are adventurers. They need to purchase and sustain some sort of transport. They must eat, drink and have a place to sleep. The spellcasters may need to purchase expensive material components, like the diamond used in resurrection spell, that must cost at least 10 000 gp. There are other factors as well, like hiring npcs, paying a spellcaster to cast a spell on them and purchasing one-time use goods like potions, scrolls. Whenever I play as either Game Master or a Player, the wealth is quite fastly used is some way.

## The question itself

The wealth should never be used when determining the character or party level, however it could affect the gained rewards, if you find that encounters were considerably easier because of the wealth.

**Modifying XP Awards and Encounter Levels**

> Sometimes, the circumstances give the characters’  opponents  a  distinct  advantage.  Other  times,  the  PCs  have  an advantage.  Adjust  the  XP  award  and  the EL  depending  on  how  greatly  circumstances change the encounter’s difficulty. (Dungeon Master's Guide, page 39)

There is also a small table, that suggests how you should modify Encounter Level and the awarded XP.

```
|       Circumstance         | XP Award Adjustment |EL Adjustment |
|   Half as difficult        |       XP × 1/2      |    EL –2     |
|Significantly less difficult|       XP x 2/3      |    EL –1     |
|Significantly more difficult|       XP × 1-1/2    |    EL +1     |
|Significantly more difficult|       XP × 2        |    EL+2      |
```

It is suggested to keep the further points in mind while modifying XP reward and ELs.

> - Experience  points  drive  the  game. Don’t be too stingy or too    generous.
> - Most encounters do not need modifying.  Don’t  waste  a  lot  of  time worrying   about   the   minutiae. Don’t worry about modifying
>   encounters until after you have played the game a while.
> - Bad  rolls  or  poor  choices  on  the  PCs’ part  should  not  modify  ELs  or  XP awards. If the encounter is difficult because the
>   players were unlucky or  careless,  they  don’t  get  more experience.
> - Just   because   the   PCs   are worn  down  from  prior  encounters does not mean that later (more difficult) encounters should
>   gain higher  awards.  Judge  the  difficulty  of  an encounter on its
>   own merits.

Comment: +1ed. That table's gold, and, I think, exactly the kind of thing the asker's looking for. Well done.

Comment: I think you misunderstand some terms yourself—particularly “wealth.”

Comment: Just as an example of how wealth might make a CR less than accurate; a +5 sword in the hands of a 2nd level fighter makes the "Challenge" far less threatening. Hence awarding less XP.

Comment: This seems like a great way to make a game extremely boring. Basically what you are saying is that if a party is overpowered compared to their level they should only encounter easy battles that give very little loot and xp, so that they take forever to level up and never progress?

Comment: @Jonathon That's kind of the problem. Encounters yielding normal rewards exacerbate the wealth problem, and, because of the PCs' wealth, encounters of *DMG* recommended difficulty are too easy. A mistake's been made—fixing it won't be as fun as not having made it in the first place.

Comment: @HeyICanChan that just seems backwards to me. Are their no good stories to be told, or adventures to be had where the party is ridiculously wealthy or has aquiered weapons many times more powerful than themselves? Or is dnd5e a system built to only tell one type of story? Or is it not the GMs job to make the game as fun as possible at all times? It seems to me that by definition nothing that happens in a dnd game is a problem if the players are having fun. And no "solution" is appropriate if it invokves punishing the players by making the game boring.

Comment: @Jonathon Are you using a *5e* lens? That's not a criticism disguised as a question; the rules are markedly different. In *3.5e* character wealth-by-level maps directly to character power. Too much PC wealth and the DM is forced to *restructure the game* because the PCs have been given too early too much power. It's really a matter, like [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115852/8610) says, of offering, for a while, alternative rewards that *don't* map directly to character power. That meantime is not necessarily unfun, but the game doesn't offer a whole lot of support for it.